# How to design a 2 way switch using Triac and SPST standard switch?

Tags: power, mains, triac, switching

I have a triac which I turn ON and OFF by giving a gate pulse through microcontroller. With the help of triac I turn ON/OFF a light in my bedroom. The bedroom light is connected to a standard SPST switch. I want to control the light (ON/OFF) using both microcontroller and SPST switch. I want to have exactly a 2 way switch action. But how could I achieve this 2 way action using SPST switch and a Triac acting like a NO switch ?

Please any feedback would be appreciated. Please find below the arrangement.

Also suggest any design or other arrangement for a 2 way action using SPST and Triac (as NO switch)

[image: Current arrangement]

Thanks in advance,
Gaurav

Comment: A relay is easier .I did this on a PIR sensor and havent replaced the relay in 17 years.

Comment: You can't turn a TRIAC off by pulsing the gate.

Comment: @EM Fields: i am using a MOC3041 to drive the gate of triac

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you wish to be able to toggle the lamp status from either the wall switch or your micro.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fslPrl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This would be the easiest way. Use two triacs triggered by seperate output pins on your micro. Make TRI2's trigger the inverted logic of TRI1. Light will be on if switch is up and TRI1 is on OR switch is down and TRI2 is on.

The other option is to use a relay changeover contact.

[Sigh] The things we do to avoid getting out of bed!

[Edit: SPST version]]

Pop a changeover relay into the circuit. Coil needs to be rated for mains voltage and AC. Contacts need to be rated for mains voltage and the lamp current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvpyOr.png)</sup>

A simpler method might be ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIceRZ.png)</sup>

Use the relay contact to signal the switch status to your micro. Let your micro then keep track of the relay signal and its local signal to determine when to switch the light on.

Comment: It would be prudent to isolate the triac terminals from the micro .You could use a opto isolator to keep it safe.

Comment: @Autistic yes i am using an optoisolator which i didn't mentioned in the question as i wanto to point out directly to my problem

Comment: @transistor: yes this is what i want to achieve but as the scheme you suggested is using SW1 which is a SPDT switch. I wish to acheive the same purpose with SW1 as SPST switch, please any ideas or alrernate scheme ? Please note that i want to use only Triac and SPST switch